# The difference between Path: and Location: in Eclipse, Properties (of the project), Resource?

Tags: java, eclipse

*Hi everyone.
I am learning how to use Eclipse and I have a little question, after reading the Frequently asked questions (FAQ) (https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_difference_between_a_path_and_a_location%3F EDIT : FOR PLUGINS).
I can't understand what the author mean ? Please help. I want to know.
Thanks.*

I use Eclipse 3.8.1 on Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: Are you writing Eclipse plugins? That FAQ only applies to plugins.

Comment: No, but I want to know the difference between the two. Are they the same thing ? (Location and Path) Post edited.

Comment: Right-click any file or folder and choose _Properties_: in _Resource_ you see both _Path_ and _Location_

Comment: @howlger Edits are supposed to be for minor corrections, please don't edit in new information that the original poster did not intend to include.

Comment: @greg-449 The _new information_ is two Javadoc links to the resource API you mentioned. Note, I have not touched your description about project relative IPath even though this was not asked (the question is about the Eclipse terms _Location_ vs. _Path_, both of type `IPath`). Anyway, I hope you're okay with my comment on your answer.

Comment: @howlger The comment is fine. The point is that this is information I specifically decided not to include because the OP said they were not doing plugin development. Edits must not 'put words in to other people's mouths', this has been discussed on Stack Overflow Meta many times.

Comment: @greg-449 From my point of view, the Javadoc of both methods is a good and detailed description of what the user sees in the _File > Properties_ dialog in _Resource_. But maybe I'm wrong and they're too technical. I wanted to enhance your answer. It was not my intention and I apologize to put words in your mouth. I do not know about these discussions on Stack Overflow Meta and I haven't been here as long as you, so I don't always know how everything is handled here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Eclipse workspace resource API a Location is an absolute path in the file system, an IPath is a relative path most often relative to the workspace root.

So if I have a workspace at `/Users/greg/workspace` and it contains a file `/project/folder/myfile.java` the workspace root relative IPath would be

```
/project/folder/myfile.java
```

The Location would be

```
/Users/greg/workspace/project/folder/myfile.java
```

You might also use a project relative IPath which would just be

```
/folder/myfile.java
```

Comment: See `IResource`: [`getFullPath()`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#getFullPath--) vs. [`getLocation()`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#getLocation--), both of type [`IPath`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath.html)